# how to append the multiple api's

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm having multiple of api's. how to i get the output.here i'm added the sample snippet. in that abc is the component. next component xyz, pqr like that.

```
let str1="http://localhost:ip/abc?text="+this.state.content;
    fetch(str1, {
        method: "GET",
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          this.setState({
            res: res.abc
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions. Assuming you want to make 3 different API requests at the same time, and use the results for React `setState`, you can do so with `Promise.all`:

```
const reqA = fetch(`http://localhost:ip/abc?text=${this.state.content}`);
const reqX = fetch(`http://localhost:ip/xyz?text=${this.state.content}`);
const reqP = fetch(`http://localhost:ip/pqr?text=${this.state.content}`);
Promise.all([reqA, reqX, reqP]).then(function(allResults) {
    Promise.all(allResults.map(res => res.json())).then(function(
        jsonResults
    ) {
        console.log("Results", jsonResults);
        // Parse, and call `setState` here
    });
});
```

The snippet above will make XHR calls to the 3 URLs at the same time, collect its result, attempt to parse the response to JSON for all 3 of the responses, and collect the results of that. At this point, you can parse, and set the response in the state.

Note that this does not include logic for dealing with errors in any of the 3 requests. You should account for that. If your request URLs are as similar as the code snippet above, then perhaps you can define a function for constructing a URL given a "component". The snippet above also does not account for the possibility that your component may become unmounted while requests are still in-flight.

Comment: It is a common pratice to destructure results as they are returned in a predictable order so instead of jsonResults you can use [resultA, resultX, resultP]

Comment: Thank you, but here i want the result for particular api result. the above snippet shows the result for 3 api's result

Comment: @sai You can choose which result to use. You don't have to use it all.

Comment: See @MosèRaguzzini comment. In the snippet above, `jsonResults` will contain an array of the responses from each `fetch`. So `jsonResults[0]` for example, will give you the JSON response from `reqA` assuming all goes well, `jsonResults[1]` for `reqX`, and so on.